# Cannot install GEF4 on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, swt, jface, eclipse-indigo, zest

When I try to install GEF4 from https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.gef/downloads
via Eclipse-> Help -> Install New Software, giving the following URL:

https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/gef4-master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/update-site

or the other two links above it, I get the following errors:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>    Software being installed: GEF4 Zest Documentation 0.1.0.201409081002 >>>>>>(org.eclipse.gef4.zest.doc.feature.group 0.1.0.201409081002)
>    Missing requirement: GEF4 FX Documentation 0.1.0.201408181558 (org.eclipse.gef4.fx.doc >0.1.0.201408181558) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv 4.4.0' but it could not >be found
>   Missing requirement: GEF4 FX Documentation 0.1.0.201409081002 (org.eclipse.gef4.fx.doc >0.1.0.201409081002) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv 4.4.0' but it could not >be found
>    Cannot satisfy dependency:
>      From: GEF4 Zest Documentation 0.1.0.201409081002 (org.eclipse.gef4.zest.doc >0.1.0.201409081002)
>      To: bundle org.eclipse.gef4.fx.doc 0.1.0
>    Cannot satisfy dependency:
>      From: GEF4 Zest Documentation 0.1.0.201409081002 >>>(org.eclipse.gef4.zest.doc.feature.group 0.1.0.201409081002)
>      To: org.eclipse.gef4.zest.doc [0.1.0.201409081002]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you check all those items when installing?

Comment: That looks like it requires Eclipse 4.4 (Luna)

Comment: @GGrec, yes I selected all of them.

Comment: I said Luna not Kepler.

Comment: @mor222 Definetly go for Luna.

Comment: @greg-449, but our development platform is Indigo anyway. you mean it is only compatible with Luna?

Comment: GEF 4 is still in development and is targeting Eclipse Mars (4.5) released next year. The current GEF 4 builds require Eclipse Luna. For Indigo you should use the version of GEF 3 for Indigo

Comment: @greg-449, I am going to use thie package:
org.eclipse.zest.layouts.algorithms.SpaceTreeLayoutAlgorithm;

Which I think is only available in GEF4->Zest2. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @greg-449, These are still errors from Luna RCP:
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: GEF4 Zest Documentation 0.1.0.201409090203 (org.eclipse.gef4.zest.doc.feature.group 0.1.0.201409090203)
  Missing requirement: GEF4 FX 0.1.0.201409090203 (org.eclipse.gef4.fx 0.1.0.201409090203) requires 'package javafx.animation 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GEF4 FX 0.1.0.201409090203 (org.eclipse.gef4.fx.feature.group 0.1.0.201409090203)
    To: org.eclipse.gef4.fx [0.1.0.2014090902